# Api rest Parse Json Array c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse json through linguee API but it does not work and I cannot figure out why. I want to get the JsonArray "real_examples" but I  still  have an error .

Here is the error :

Unhandled Exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Here is the code :

```
public  class MyLinguee
{
    private const string URL = "https://leafword.herokuapp.com/api";
    private string urlParameters = "?q=parler&src=fr&dst=en";
    public void MyDescript()
    {


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response.ToString());
            JArray MyDescriptList = (JArray)joResponse["real_examples"];

            string src = Convert.ToString(MyDescriptList[0]);

            Console.WriteLine("descrypt : " + src);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("descryptdo not work");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Json format :

```
{
    "src_lang": "fr",
    "dst_lang": "en",
    "query": "parler",
    "correct_query": "parler",
    "inexact_matches": null,
    "real_examples": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "src": "Pour ne pas parler d'autres objectifs [...] consacrés auparavant et réaffirmés maintenant.",
            "dst": "Not to mention other objectives [...] which had been previously enshrined and which have now been reaffirmed.",
            "url": "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20020925+ITEMS+DOC+XML+V0//FR\u0026amp;language=FR"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "src": "Cela prouve que l'on ne peut pas parler de handicap, que nous sommes considérés comme des participants à part entière [...] dans les discussions économiques.",
            "dst": "This shows that there is no obstacle and that we are seen as a fully fledged participant in economic discussions.",
            "url": "http://consilium.europa.eu/showFocus.aspx?lang=FR\u0026focusID=340"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "src": "Ce succès s'explique par la qualité des préparatifs menés à tous les niveaux par l'ensemble des acteurs concernés, sans parler de l'accueil enthousiaste de la part du public.",
            "dst": "This success can be attributed to the quality of the preparations made by all players involved and at all levels, not to mention the enthusiastic reception of the general public.",
            "url": "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/key/date/2005/html/sp050114.fr.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `JObject.Parse(response.ToString())` is your problem. You want the data from `response.Content`

Comment: You might also be getting a error response from the server because you have included the URL parameters twice - once in the URL and once in the parameters argument to `GetAsync`.  I'd also suggest making the method `async` or you could potentially run into deadlock issues.

Comment: Please I am a novice can you send me an example

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response consist of many properties amongst them *Content*, which is what interest you, but its type is StreamContent and ToString() will not give you the desired output. Fortunately StreamContent has a method for reading it a a string. Try changing reading a response to :

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

And in the signature of you method add *async* keyword:

```
public async static void MyDescript()
```